# AIX P740 Server need to be upgrade SDDPCM version

Tags: aix

I am try to upgrade SDDPCM version, when i trying to install means below error will occur.

```
#installp -aXY devices.sddpcm.61.rte 
Out of memory, malloc() failed. 
0503-003 installp: The specified device /dev/rfd0 
is not a valid device or file.
```

How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `installp` where the fileset is,

`installp -aXY -d . devices.sddpcm.61.rte`

The `-d .` tells it to look in the current directory, or you could of course give it the full path.

I don't know if that will fix the other errors, but start there.